# CPLEX Adding an Integrality Constraint for a Sum of Variables

Tags: integer, cplex

I have a problem in which a sum of decision variables must be integral, however, the variables themselves do not need to be individually integral. Is there a way I can specify such constraint in CPLEX.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to introduce a new integer variable and just add a constraint such as:

```
x1 + x2 + x3 - i1 = 0
```

Where the `x` variables are the decision variables and `i1` is the new integer variable.  Then, you could also impose bounds on `i1` if you want the sum to be in a certain range (e.g., `0 <= i1 <= 10`).

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed!